# web gRPC + NGINX TLS configuration

Tags: ssl, nginx, grpc, grpc-node, grpc-web

I have a Node gRPC server and an web gRPC client (TS with Angular). I am using Nginx as a proxy to facilitate communication between them.

I don't know how to configure the web gRPC client (TS) with SSL. I tried using my current Nginx config and Node config with a Node gRPC client (not web gRPC). It worked in that case.

Node js config:
[Node Js Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckz3G.png)

Script to generate certificates:

```
openssl genrsa -passout pass:1111 -des3 -out ca.key 4096

openssl req -passin pass:1111 -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -subj  "/C=CL/ST=RM/L=Santiago/O=Test/OU=Test/CN=ca"

openssl genrsa -passout pass:1111 -des3 -out server.key 4096

openssl req -passin pass:1111 -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj  "/C=CL/ST=RM/L=Santiago/O=Test/OU=Server/CN=dev"

openssl x509 -req -passin pass:1111 -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt

openssl rsa -passin pass:1111 -in server.key -out server.key

openssl genrsa -passout pass:1111 -des3 -out client.key 4096

openssl req -passin pass:1111 -new -key client.key -out client.csr -subj  "/C=CL/ST=RM/L=Santiago/O=Test/OU=Client/CN=dev"

openssl x509 -passin pass:1111 -req -days 365 -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out client.crt

openssl rsa -passin pass:1111 -in client.key -out client.key
```

On the above code, in CN=dev, dev is the DNS entry in my server's etc/hosts file pointing to server's own address.

Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 10002 ssl http2;
    # listen 10002 http2;
    # include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    #  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    ssl_certificate     certs/client.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key certs/client.key;

    if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
        return 204;
    }

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
    add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 3600;
    add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Content-Length;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers Range;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers x-user-agent;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers x-grpc-web;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers content-type;

    grpc_ssl_certificate certs/client.crt;
    grpc_ssl_certificate_key certs/client.key;
    grpc_ssl_trusted_certificate certs/ca.crt;
    grpc_ssl_name ace-dev;
    grpc_ssl_server_name on;    

    # location /Forms.Forms/getExistingForms{
    #   grpc_pass grpcs://backend;
    # };

    location / {
         grpc_pass grpcs://192.168.1.59:50051;
    } 
    #ssl_certificate     ssl/cert.pem;
    #ssl_certificate_key ssl/key.pem;
    #...
}
```

Now,the web gRPC portion (Not working gives handshake error, no proper documentation how to do it, so tried looking at [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/pull/125) and grpcWeb source code and assumed it would go this way) :
[web gRPC TLS config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjCHH.png)

This is all I have right now. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx is no longer being actively supported for grpc-web. Nginx, out of the box, doesn't understand grpc-web request. The default proxy that supports grpc-web is Envoy. You can look up how to configure Envoy with their documentations.